# Javafx TableView tabelmenubutton CSS Stylesheet

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, stylesheet

By setting setTableMenuButtonVisible(true) on my tableview, I am able to see a button with a "+" sign on the top right corner, where u can select to show/hide columns. I wish to use a stylesheet to change the background color as well as the label colours etc but nothing works. I've tried the following:

```
.button
.toggle-button,
.menu-button {
   -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always when it is about JavaFX styling, I recommand to use the Oracle documentation in order to see what compose the control (in your case the [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tableview) and to search the default styling for each element in [Modena.css](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470) (the default styling sheet since JavaFx 8).
Knowing that it is easy to style the table menu button :

```
/**
 * For styling only the "+" button on the right top corner
 */
 .table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}


/**
 * In order to style any other column header's background
 */
.table-view .column-header {
    -fx-background-color : yellow;
}


/**
 * For styling column header's labels
 */
.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-text-fill : green;
}
```

Comment: Splendid! Yeah I'm working in an offline environment and googled using my phone.. it got real difficult and I couldn't find it.. Thank you so much

Comment: Ahaha, it happens to me some years ago, it was definitily not the best part of my professional career. Good luck.